# app crash and doesn't display Toast message

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android development. I want to display a Toast message when the app is not installed. When the app is not installed, for example the Facebook app, the app is crashing. What is the problem in my code?

```
case R.id.Facebook:
    Intent facebook = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.katana");
    startActivity(facebook);
    if (facebook != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Facebook is not installed ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: Move `startActivity(facebook);` inside if block and you need to call `.show()` to make Toast visible

Comment: Facebook does not exist in your device meaning the value of facebook is null; it implies then that you are starting an activity that does not exist;

Comment: doesn't work app crash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You check for null too late, try this:

```
case R.id.Facebook:
    Intent facebook = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.katana");
    if (facebook == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Facebook is not installed ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
       startActivity(facebook);
    }
    return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

to display toast you need to call `.show()` on toast object

Comment: Should consider moving this answer to the comment section!